# rsync output (ongoing) not recorded in new log file after rotation with newsyslog

Tags: freebsd, rsync

I discovered this morning that on-going rsync output does not appear in the rsync log after rotation by newsyslog.  It is lost

In other words,

- a running rsync is logging to /var/log/rsync
- newsyslog does the log rotation
- no output appears in the new /var/log/rsync.
- Output is not   captured anywhere that I can see.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the rsync command (pulls from an rsyncd module on a windows box running cygwin). It is part of an rsnapshot command, but that is not germane to this problem.

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync -av --delete --relative --delete-excluded --stats --log-file=/var/log/rsync --human-readable --no-owner --no-group --exclude-from=/yada/yada/.rsnapshot_excludes 192.168.3.130::INC-10890_data/ /zfspoolname/archives/daily.0/LOCATIONSIGNIFIER/INC-10890_data/
```

Here are the last 5 lines of /var/log/rsync.0 (after unzipping).

```
[root@offsite1 ~]# tail -5 /var/log/rsync.0
2019/02/11 01:03:54 [20023] >f+++++++++ master/20170801/000054420170801010001/000054420170801010001oct_c_102.bmp
2019/02/11 01:03:55 [20023] >f+++++++++ master/20170801/000054420170801010001/000054420170801010001oct_c_103.bmp
2019/02/11 01:03:55 [20023] >f+++++++++ master/20170801/000054420170801010001/000054420170801010001oct_c_104.bmp
2019/02/11 01:03:55 [20023] >f+++++++++ master/20170801/000054420170801010001/000054420170801010001oct_c_105.bmp
2019/02/11 01:03:55 [20023] >f+++++++++ master/20170801/000054420170801010001/000054420170801010001oct_c_106.bmp
```

Here's what is in /var/log/rsync:

```
> [root@offsite1 ~]# tail -5 /var/log/rsync   Feb 11 01:00:00 offsite1
> newsyslog[61988]: logfile turned over
```

Here are the last few lines of what was on my screen when I killed the rsync job this morning (I left the command tail -f /var/log/rsync running over night).  This should show up in /var/log/rsync, since I was running a tail -f on it.  I have experience of this type of output appearing in /var/log/rsync when newsyslog is not involved.

```
> 2019/02/11 07:13:52 [20023] >f+++++++++
> master/20170914/000504720170914030001/000504720170914030001oct_c_027.bmp
> 2019/02/11 07:13:52 [20023] >f+++++++++
> master/20170914/000504720170914030001/000504720170914030001oct_c_028.bmp
> 2019/02/11 07:13:53 [20023] >f+++++++++
> master/20170914/000504720170914030001/000504720170914030001oct_c_029.bmp
> 2019/02/11 07:13:53 [20023] >f+++++++++
> master/20170914/000504720170914030001/000504720170914030001oct_c_030.bmp
> 2019/02/11 07:13:53 [20023] >f+++++++++
> master/20170914/000504720170914030001/000504720170914030001oct_c_031.bmp
> 2019/02/11 07:13:53 [20023] >f+++++++++
> master/20170914/000504720170914030001/000504720170914030001oct_c_032.bmp
> 2019/02/11 07:13:54 [12868] rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or
> SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(689) [generator=3.1.3] 2019/02/11 07:13:54
> [20023] rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at
> io.c(504) [receiver=3.1.3]
```

Here's what's in /usr/local/etc/newsyslog.conf.d/rsync

```
#
# The 'flags' field is one or more of the letters: BCDGJNUXZ or a '-'.
#
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/var/log/rsync                          644  13    *    $W1D01 JCN
```

and finally

```
[root@offsite1 ~]# uname -a
FreeBSD offsite1.domanname.com 12.0-RELEASE-p3 FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p3 GENERIC  amd64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newsyslog` will move the logfile to a new name (`/var/log/rsync.0`) and compress it (to `/var/log/rsync.0.bz2`, due to the `J` flag that you use in `newsyslog.conf`).  It then creates a new file with the old name (the `C` flag in `newsyslog.conf`).

This means that the process(es) writing to that file will write to a file which does no longer exist (well, it does, but without a name).  The inode that corresponded to `/var/log/rsync` will no longer have a name and the space used by the file will be reclaimed once `rsync` closes the filehandle. The inode lost its name when the file was compressed.

Usually, system services are sent the `HUP` signal by `newsyslog` and usually that means that they will *reopen* their logfiles for writing.  This means that they will start writing to the newly cleared out logfile, and not into the void.

`rsync` does not have that facility as far as I know, so everything that is written after point where the logfile is rotated will be lost.

Depending on how the backed up `rsync.0` file is created, you may possibly have `rsync` continue writing to *that* file if you simply disable compression of the rotated logs.

You can do this by using the `p` flag in the flag column of `newsyslog.conf`, which will leave the zeroth rotated log file uncompressed but compress the older ones.  See [`newsyslog.conf(8)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=newsyslog.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

Note that disabling compression of the first log only would still cause issues if the same `rsync` process stays alive over the *second* log file rotation, as the `rsync.0` file would be renamed into `rsync.1` and then compressed to `rsync.1.bz2` (it's the same problem all over again).  Disabling log file compression *completely* would sort that out.

Comment: @BISI By "flag", I mean the flags used in the flag column in `newsyslog.conf`.  You currently use `JCN`.  You could try changing this to `JCNP`. Again, see the `newsyslog.conf` manual.  The `-P` _option_ to `newsyslog` does something completely different and will not solve anything for you.

Comment: thank you, @Kusalananda, for the clarification.  I was reading newsyslog(8) man page.  The description for -P didn't make a lot of sense, but....  so, there it is, plain as day in the (newsyslog.conf) man page: " 'p'       indicates that the zero-th rotated file should not be compressed"  It seems odd that the it is a lower case p and is the only lower-case flag.  I will force a rotation and see what happens.

Comment: @BISI You know, I did not notice either that the flag was lower case (corrected in the answer just now). Thanks!

Comment: verified the solution by (1) having a long-running rsync command, (2) changing the flags in /usr/local/etc/newsyslog.conf.d/rsync to JCNp. (3)issuing the command newsyslog -F /var/log/rsync.   The rsync.0 file continues to record the output from the rsync process that was running at the time of the log rotation.  And the rsync.0 file that I had decompressed earlier to check that the output truly was lost was moved to rsync.1.bz2 (that is, rotated and compressed).

Comment: @BISI Good! See added bit about _very_ long running `rsync` jobs. I don't know if it applies to you.

Comment: In this case, no, but good clarification!  I rotate the log weekly, and I normally expect the job will only last an hour or two.  This is an exceptional circumstance -- the client dumped in tens of thousands of image files (optometry clinic), and I am baby-sitting the process of catching up on copying the files during the off-hours, so the rsync job ran over the weekly rotation at one point.  Only about a week of more baby-sitting 'til it's back to normal, and everything fits together nicely.  Wish I could upvote your answer